# Геометрия жёсткого диска

Tags: delphi

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как на Delphi определить по полному пути файла, на каких и скольких кластерах он размещается (ну файл).

Comment: К геометрии жесткого диска вопрос отношения не имеет. Что можно узнать по-простому, так это - размер файла в байтах и размер файла в кластерах. Получить это все можно через стандартные ф-ции Win32API. А вот на каких кластерах лежит файл - это, извините, нужно уже самому писать работу с файловой системой.

Answer (score 3):

`GetFileSizeEx()` даст вам размер файла. `GetDiskFreeSpace()` даст вам размер кластера для диска. Поделили одно на другое, получили размер в кластерах.

Обратиться из Дельфи к этим функциям WinAPI вы можете, определив их как

```
 stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
```

Что касается того, на *каких* кластерах лежит файл, то тут уже нужно поглубже залезть в файловые системы и разобраться, что можно пихать в `DeviceIoControl()`.

Вот вам статья с примером в помощь: [Finding Disk Sectors Associated with File Records](http://www.wd-3.com/archive/luserland.htm).

Comment: `GetDiskFreeSpace()` возвращает размер свободной области, а не размер кластера.

Comment: @СергейПлахов, третий параметр функции, `lpBytesPerSector`, используется для возврата именно размера кластера в байтах.